# Unable to exclude /var/log monitoring in tripwire?

Tags: linux, tripwire

I am trying to exclude /var/log monitoring by commenting that line

```
 /var/run                          -> $(SEC_CONFIG) ;
#/var/log                          -> $(SEC_CONFIG) ;
#/etc/ioctl.save                   -> $(SEC_CONFIG) ;
 /etc/issue.net                    -> $(SEC_CONFIG) -i ; # Inode number changes
 /etc/issue                        -> $(SEC_CONFIG) ;
```

After committing the changes

```
tripwire --check --interactive
```

When i do the modification under /var/log and re-run the report it still report voilation under /var/log

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rule Name: System boot changes (/var/log)
Severity Level: 100
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Modified:
"/var/log/sa/sar06"
```

Total violations found:  1

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
tripwire --update-policy --secure-mode low /etc/tripwire/twpol.txt
```

This helped to update the singed policy file and checks excluded that folder